# MySQL: Column Generated From a Self-Referencing (?) SELECT Query

Tags: mysql

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how the column `product_count` works. It seems to be somehow referencing itself with aliases `see` and `e`, which are both pointing to `catalog_category_entity`. Specifically,

```
WHERE (see.entity_id = e.entity_id) OR (see.path LIKE CONCAT(e.path, '/%'))
```

Both `see` and `e` are aliases for table `catalog_category_entity`. What is this doing?

Here's the entire query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `d_name`.`value` AS `name`, IF(s_name.value_id > 0, s_name.value, d_name.value) AS `name`, `d_is_active`.`value` AS `is_active`, IF(s_is_active.value_id > 0, s_is_active.value, d_is_active.value) AS `is_active`, `d_is_anchor`.`value` AS `is_anchor`, IF(s_is_anchor.value_id > 0, s_is_anchor.value, d_is_anchor.value) AS `is_anchor`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT scp.product_id)
        FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `see`
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `scp`
                ON see.entity_id=scp.category_id
        WHERE (see.entity_id = e.entity_id) OR (see.path LIKE CONCAT(e.path, '/%'))
    ) AS `product_count`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(cp.product_id)
        FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `cp`
        WHERE (cp.category_id = e.entity_id)
    ) AS `self_product_count`
FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `d_name` ON d_name.entity_id=e.entity_id AND d_name.attribute_id=41 AND d_name.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND d_name.store_id=0
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `s_name` ON s_name.entity_id=e.entity_id AND s_name.attribute_id=41 AND s_name.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND s_name.store_id=0
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `d_is_active` ON d_is_active.entity_id=e.entity_id AND d_is_active.attribute_id=42 AND d_is_active.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND d_is_active.store_id=0
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `s_is_active` ON s_is_active.entity_id=e.entity_id AND s_is_active.attribute_id=42 AND s_is_active.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND s_is_active.store_id=0
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `d_is_anchor` ON d_is_anchor.entity_id=e.entity_id AND d_is_anchor.attribute_id=51 AND d_is_anchor.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND d_is_anchor.store_id=0
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `s_is_anchor` ON s_is_anchor.entity_id=e.entity_id AND s_is_anchor.attribute_id=51 AND s_is_anchor.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id AND s_is_anchor.store_id=0
WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (e.entity_id IN('24', '533')) ORDER BY LENGTH(e.path) ASC
```

Comment: this is maybe the most self joined query I ever saw. what are you trying to achieve with it? I bet there are far better ways to get you there......

Comment: I returns the product counts, among many other things, of categories `24` and `533`. I didn't write this, and I'm just wondering how that `product_count` column's `WHERE` statement works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a correlated query, here the query owner is checking a condition from outside of the sub-query with an `OR` clause.

In the below sub-query there is a `distinct` `count` of `production_id` which should exist in both tables: `catalog_category_entity` and `catalog_category_product` (even here there is no requirement of left join and an inner join may work better as you get count from the right side table) with condition that either `entitiy_id` should exist in `catalog_category_entity` as main table `OR` sub-query path field should match with the main table left part of path field means the main table may contain an extra string in right side but the left part should be same.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT scp.product_id)
    FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `see`
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `scp`
        ON see.entity_id=scp.category_id
    WHERE (see.entity_id = e.entity_id)
    OR (see.path LIKE CONCAT(e.path, '/%'))
```

You can simplify your query if the requirement is clear as you are joining table `catalog_category_entity_int` 4 times with left join, while you can use as below only a single time:

```
LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_int` AS `d_is_anchor`
ON d_is_anchor.entity_id=e.entity_id
    AND d_is_anchor.attribute_id IN (42,51)
    AND d_is_anchor.entity_type_id=e.entity_type_id
    AND d_is_anchor.store_id=0
```

Comment: I get everything else other than the comparison between `see` and `e` because they're both aliases for the main table `catalog_category_entity`. So what is `see.entity_id = e.entity_id`?

Comment: I followed up and read about correlated subqueries, and I understand it now. The subquery's `WHERE` (e.g. `see.entity_id = e.entity_id`) is using the data returned from the outer query (i.e. `e.entity_id`s from the outer `SELECT`.